# MAX DATE in a result

Tags: sql, db2

```
select
```

Little bit of background, I am pulling live data from an IBM AS400, I have no SQL tables, I am connecting to the tables via ODBC, using QTODBC to create my queries, then I export them to Power Bi.

In my previous question I asked how to get the latest MAX date for each row for which I got an answer.

```
select * from (
    select HVSERN, row_number() over (partition by HVSERN order by HVTDAT desc) as rn, HVUSER
    from SERH 
    Where HVSERN = '519488536') t where t.rn = 1
```

To which I don't know how to left join that into my main query.

I am trying to get the most recent date from HVTDAT - LastTouch

```
SELECT

HTSTKL as StockLoc,
HTBINL as Bin,
HTPART as Part,
IFNULL(AVMAJG, AWMAJG) AS MAJG,
IFNULL(AVMING, AWMING) as MING,
HTSERN as Serial,
HVTDAT as LastTouch,
HVUSER as User,
(HTQTY - HTQTYC) as LabelQty,
HTLOTN as LOTN,
IFNULL(ICSTM.CGSTCS, ICSTP.CHSTCS) AS cost,
((HTQTY - HTQTYC) * IFNULL(ICSTM.CGSTCS, ICSTP.CHSTCS)) as Value

FROM SERI


left join STKMM on SERI.HTPART = STKMM.AVPART
left join STKMP on SERI.HTPART = STKMP.AWPART
left join ICSTP on SERI.HTPART = ICSTP.CHPART and SERI.HTPLNT = ICSTP.CHPLNT
left join ICSTM on SERI.HTPART = ICSTM.CGPART and SERI.HTPLNT = ICSTM.CGPLNT
left join SERH on SERI.HTSERN = SERH.HVSERN



where SERI.HTSTS = 'A'
and SERI.HTSTKL <> ' '
and seri.htplnt = 'GC'
and htsern = '519488536'
```

I am looking for the most recent result in this query, which was made on 2019-07-24 for serial 519488536

[image]

Comment: Just as a comment: in IBM i (iSeries or AS/400), what they call Physical Files are actually tables, and Logical Files are views... So don't let IBM i people confuse you with their terms.  Internally tables are equally managed no matter if they were created using SQL DDL or native DDS.  The only tricky thing are "members", which does not have equivalent in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for `max()` date per serial number:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
HTSTKL as StockLoc,
HTBINL as Bin,
HTPART as Part,
IFNULL(AVMAJG, AWMAJG) AS MAJG,
IFNULL(AVMING, AWMING) as MING,
HTSERN as Serial,
HVTDAT as LastTouch,
HVUSER as User,
(HTQTY - HTQTYC) as LabelQty,
HTLOTN as LOTN,
IFNULL(ICSTM.CGSTCS, ICSTP.CHSTCS) AS cost,
((HTQTY - HTQTYC) * IFNULL(ICSTM.CGSTCS, ICSTP.CHSTCS)) as Value
, row_number() over (partition by SERH.HVSERN order by SERH.HVTDAT desc) as rn
FROM SERI
left join STKMM on SERI.HTPART = STKMM.AVPART
left join STKMP on SERI.HTPART = STKMP.AWPART
left join ICSTP on SERI.HTPART = ICSTP.CHPART and SERI.HTPLNT = ICSTP.CHPLNT
left join ICSTM on SERI.HTPART = ICSTM.CGPART and SERI.HTPLNT = ICSTM.CGPLNT
left join SERH on SERI.HTSERN = SERH.HVSERN
where SERI.HTSTS = 'A'
and SERI.HTSTKL <> ' '
and seri.htplnt = 'GC'
and htsern = '519488536') t1 where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: You are a genius, thank you for answering my question and teaching me this trick.